# Multiple hops SSH tunnel

Tags: bash

I need to open an ssh tunnel through to an oracle database port...after much fluffing around I cant seem to get it to work.

Here is the scenario...

My Machine --> host1 --> host2 --> oracle_instance(host3)...

So i need to be able to go through host1 which knows about host2...then from host2 to the oracle_instance on host3.

This is in order to connect up my sql developer.

Therefore I should be able telnet to the local port on my machine which will in effect be forwarding traffic from the oracle_instance port...

Any help much appreciated...

Answer (score 3):

Add a stanza to `~/.ssh/config`:

```
Host oracletunnel
    ProxyCommand ssh host1user@host1 nc host2 22
```

Then use `ssh host2user@oracletunnel -L <port>:host3:<port>`.

Comment: Hi,Thanks for your reply...but how do I exactly type this command out...?  And the addition of the commands to .ssh/config...?  Can you output an example ~/.ssh/config...?

Comment: It's right up there in my answer. Open `~/.ssh/config` in a text editor and add those lines.