# How can I use SSH as an arbitrary channel through a bastion host?

Tags: ssh, tunnel

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Multiple hops SSH tunnel…](https://superuser.com/questions/185921/multiple-hops-ssh-tunnel)

Here's the setup:

**desktop**: my desktop.  I have root and can do anything I want.  Kubuntu 10.04.

**bastion**: a bastion host that only allows inbound SSH connections on port 22.  I do not control this server.  I cannot write files anywhere on this server.  The only commands available to me are `ssh`  and shell (bash) builtins.  CentOS.

**server**: a server with a file on it that I want to retrieve (i.e. copy to **desktop**).  Only allows incoming SSH connections from **bastion**.  Does not allow outgoing ssh connections.  CentOS.

I can ssh from **desktop** to **bastion**, and then ssh from **bastion** to **server**. I can set up an SSH tunnel on B as follows:

```
ssh -fNL 30000:localhost:22 server
```

And then the following allows me to connect to **server** from **bastion**:

```
bastion % ssh localhost -p 30000
```

But this does not work (**bastion** refuses the connection):

```
desktop % ssh bastion -p 30000
```

I'm wondering if there's some way I can turn an ssh session from **desktop** to **bastion** into a tunnel that connects to port 30000 locally on **bastion**, so that I can then go through that connection to get to **server**. If bastion allowed incoming connections on high ports, I could do it, but it doesn't, only port 22.

I know that there's other options: I could cat the target file to my screen and save it out locally, but this is a hack (and annoying if there's binary data in the file).

**EDIT:** I figured out one stupid solution:

```
bastion % ssh server "cat filename1" | ssh localhost "cat > filename2"
```

This works, although the ssh prompts (are you sure you want to connect, yes/no? and the password) get in each others' way so you have to type "yes" and the various host passwords in the correct order).  But it would be nice if I could tunnel through to **server** from **desktop**.

Answer (score 1):

First, connect to bastion and set up a tunnel from `desktop` -> `bastion`
`ssh -L 30000:localhost:30000 bastion`

Now set up a tunnel from `bastion` -> `server` by running this on `bastion`
`ssh -L 30000:localhost:22 server`

Now you can `sftp server:30000:/path/to/the/file/you/want.txt` to pull the file into your current directory.

The first two commands can be simplified by just running
`ssh -L 30000:localhost:30000 bastion ssh -L 30000:localhost:22 server`
 from the desktop I *think*.

**EDIT**:

Try `ssh -L 30000:server:22 bastion`

Comment: The first command doesn't work; bastion won't accept an incoming SSH request on port 30000.

Comment: I just thought of something, see my modified commands.